# Wordpress pagination custom css

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a question about wordpress pagination custome css.In my category.php,i use the follow code to display the pagination

```
$args = [
                    'prev_text'=>'&laquo;',
                    'next_text'=>'&raquo;',
                    'type'=>'list'
        ];
        echo paginate_links($args);
```

then it output a `<ul>` with some `<li>` tags.but i want to modify the `class` attribute of `ul` tag,the default `class` attribute is `page-numbers`,i want to it change to be `pagination`,so how can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While echoing replace the class name like this:

```
echo str_replace( "<ul class='page-numbers'>", '<ul class="pagination">', paginate_links($args));
```

Comment: Thank you.on,my god! I have searched many ways to make it,but i couldn't believe i forget this simple way.~~~~(>_<)~~~~

Answer (score 0):

paginate_links() doesn't offer a parameter and there are no hooks - see source - available to change the class(es). Which means you can do it like you have done it or you create your own pagination function based on paginate_links().

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the pagination with a class of your own:

```
echo '<div class="my-pagination'>;
echo paginate_links( $args );
echo '</div>';
```

Then you can style it any way you want:

```
.my-pagination ul {
    /* whatever you want */
}
```